# Select random <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, html5-audio, shuffle

I'm trying to make a shuffle button for my HTML 5 player. My player is set up like this to go the next track:

```
    $('.nextbutton').on("click", function(){
    var next = $('li.playing').next();
        if (!next.length) next = $('#stuff ul li').first();
        next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
        var title = $('a#tunes img', next).attr("title");
            $("a.songtitle span").text(title);
        var artist = $('a#tunes img', next).attr("artist");
            $("a.songartist span").text(artist);
        audio.load($('a#tunes', next).attr('data-src'));
        audio.play();
    });
```

This code works to go to the next song but how can I change this to make it so it selects a random `<li>` element instead of the `.next();` `<li>`? Thanks for your time and consideration. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var next = Math.floor(Math.random() * jQuery('#stuff ul li').length + 1));
var nextLi = jQuery('#stuff ul li').get(next);
```

It'll get random number between 0 and count of `li`s and then get this `li`.

Comment: Thank you for your time! That didn't seem to work for me. I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MXQaz/23/. Maybe you can help me see what I'm doing wrong. The shuffle button is labeled in the javascript. Thanks!

Comment: @jick Change `$('#stuff ul li').get(rand)` to `$($('#stuff ul li').get(rand))` to convert `li` to jquery object.

Comment: That did it! Except I also had to remove the "+1" from "jQuery('#stuff ul li').length + 1);". Thanks so much again! Here's the updated fiddle if you want to check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/MXQaz/32/

Answer (score 1):

you can use a random number generator like

```
var rand =  Math.floor(Math.random() * jQuery('#stuff ul li').length + 1);
```

or

```
var rand =  Math.ceil(Math.random() *( jQuery('#stuff ul li').length + 1));
```

for getting a random song number in the list , and then get the corresponding item like this:

```
var next = $('#stuff ul li').get(rand);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help! Those didn't seem to work. I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MXQaz/23/. Maybe you can tell me what I'm doing wrong? The shuffle button is labeled in the javascript. Thanks again!