# Pick a random quote each hour

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, quote

I would like to add that certain something to my page with a little motivational quote, which changes like every hour or day. 
I wanted to write down all the quotes in a document and javascript (or what else) picks one of these quotes every day and put them on my page.
I thought it might work with a list, like:

```
<ul>
   <li>It’s not that I’m so smart, it’s just that I stay with problems longer.</li>
   <li>Eighty percent of success is showing up.</li>
   <li>I respect faith, but doubt is what gets you an education.</li>
   <li>...</li>
<ul>
```

Is that possible in a way or do i have to change them manually (with a CMS probably or directly in HTML)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: "Is that possible in a way": Yes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352358/select-random-li-element May be this is helpful for you.

Comment: Do you mean that ALL visitors of this page should see the same quote during one hour?
Or it should be random for each page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally possible, but, without any server-side code you wouldn't have a way to ensure the same message would be shown to every visitant, or even the same visitant in another browser instance. I wrote something that would work as:
Pick a random message between a time set of messages, each time someone enters your page it takes a random one, see:

```
var phrases = [
    {
      hour: 0,
      content : [
        "Be or not to be",
        "Foo",
        "Bar"
      ]
    },
    {
      hour: 1,
      content : [
        "Be or not to be",
        "Foo",
        "Bar"
      ]
    }
];

var phrase = undefined; //get one randomly based on new Date().getHours()
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   document.getElementById('phrase').innerHTML = phrase;
});
```

For full example see:

https://plnkr.co/edit/tBcH5DYxYTxl2kBtp0yk?p=preview

Just an idea, hope it helps you. If you want the same message to be shown to  everybody keep just one message per hour. I mean, this is a "server free" option. This will show the same messages everyday, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I cant say for picking a quote every hour or day, but there could be a different quote everytime the page is refreshed. You could store the quotes in a table and give each quote an id. Then, in your page, you have to connect to the database and call a random id,
this can be done with :

int rand ( int $min , int $max )

which returns an integer between $min and $max ( In your case, the min and max id).
Then the quote corresponding to that id will be displayed.
P.S I know this does not answer your question, but its a suggestion (Since I'm not reputed enough to comment :P )

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!